# Is it possible to reproduce several videos automatically in different screens?

Tags: video, boot, automation, vlc-media-player

I'm planning to build a system with a graphic card that supports 6 outputs (a Radeon Eyefinity) and I'd like to play in each screen a different file, which would be looped indefinitely.

For now I think that's possible to accomplish manually as long as the processor can keep up with it, I mean, VLC or MPC-HC both support to be opened several times playing different files and looping the reproduction.

But I'd like for it to be autonomous, in the sense that I'd like that computer to start and after loading everything start playing the videos. And that is the tricky part I think, how to tell each player to start (ideally maximized) in its screen playing its file.

Is there anything you can think of that I can try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a script and use mpc-hc, here's an example

```
mpc-hc.exe <file> /fullscreen /monitor <N> /play
```

Where `<N>` is the monitor you want the video to be played in.

Answer (score 1):

You can script VLC, telling it which monitor and window state (etc.) to start with via command-line arguments:

```
  --directx-device={}
      In a multiple monitor configuration, you can specify the Windows
      device name of the display that you want the video window to open on.
      For example, "\\.\DISPLAY1" or "\\.\DISPLAY2".
```

.

```
  -L, --loop, --no-loop
      VLC will keep playing the playlist indefinitely. (default disabled)
```

.

```
  -f, --fullscreen, --no-fullscreen
      Start video in fullscreen mode (default disabled)
```

.

```
  --playlist-autostart, --no-playlist-autostart
      Automatically start playing the playlist content once it's loaded.
      (default enabled)
```

More info: [Full VLC command-line argument list](https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help)

Put that script into the startup routine of the OS and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the info, I marked the other one as the accepted answer because it seems to be easier on the display naming, but both answers are equally useful. Apparently only one can be marked as accepted.